# Поменять местами минимальный и максимальный элемент. Ошибка

Tags: python, python-3.x, оператор-присваивания

В списке все элементы различны. Код должен поменять местами минимальный и максимальный элемент, но при вводе некоторых данных *3 4 5 2 1* работает неправильно

```
listo = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
listo[listo.index(max(listo))], listo[listo.index(min(listo))] = 
listo[listo.index(min(listo))], listo[listo.index(max(listo))]
for i in listo:
    print(i, end = " ")
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listo = [int(i) for i in input().split()]

print(listo)
[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]

in_min, in_max = listo.index(min(listo)), listo.index(max(listo))

listo[in_max], listo[in_min] = listo[in_min], listo[in_max]

print(listo)
[3, 4, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: `listo[in_max], listo[in_min] = listo[in_min], listo[in_max]`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо, исправился )

Answer (score 6):

> Почему так происходит?

Смотрите, когда вы написали код с `max` и `index`, то не учли, что код выполняется.

```
listo[listo.index(max(listo))], listo[listo.index(min(listo))] = listo[listo.index(min(listo))], listo[listo.index(max(listo))]
```

---

Давайте покажу что происходит в вашем коде на небольшом примере.

```
class Foo:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(item)
        return item
    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        print(item, value)

foo = Foo()
foo[1], foo[2] = foo[3], foo[4]
```

В консоли будет:

```
3
4
1 3
2 4
```

Т.е. сначала обрабатывается код после `=`, а после выполняется присваивание по-элементно правой к левой части.

---

Теперь ваш код.

У `listo` будет значение `[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]`:

```
listo[listo.index(max(listo))], # Шаг 3
listo[listo.index(min(listo))]  # Шаг 4
= 
listo[listo.index(min(listo))], # Шаг 1
listo[listo.index(max(listo))]  # Шаг 2
```

Шаги:

- Шаг 1. Значение 1, индекс 4, возвращаем 1
- Шаг 2. Значение 5, индекс 2, возвращаем 5
- Шаг 3. Значение 5, индекс 2, присваиваем 1. Список изменился и стал `[3, 4, 1, 2, 1]`
- Шаг 4. Значение 1, индекс 2, присваиваем 5. Список стал `[3, 4, 5, 2, 1]`

На Шаге 3 мы список изменили, и после этого алгоритм сломался. Поэтому индексы минимального и максимального элемента нужно найти до обмена.